# Scaling a probability histogram to represent a different time-scale

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a series of $N$ measurements $m$ taken at regular intervals $\Delta t$, say every 10 minutes.

From these, I can build a probability histogram $P(m)$ reporting on the $y$ axis the number of occurences of a certain measure. I could then calculate the product $P(m) \Delta t$ and obtain the amount of time a measure $m$ occurred, measured in minutes.

[This picture may help clarifying my thoughts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7O3f.png)

How can I scale $P(m) \Delta t$ to represent the number of occurrences *per hour*?

Comment: When you say "a probability histogram $P(m)$ reporting on the $y$ axis the number of occurrences" do you mean that $P(m)$ is the proportion of occurrences or the number of occurrences in a given time interval or something else? Why are you then multiplying by $\Delta t$ rather than dividing by it?  Is $\Delta t$ measured in minutes or hours?

Comment: $P(m)$ is the number of occurrences in a given measure bin, so that if I sum all the occurrences in the bins I obtain the total number of observations.
By multiplying that for $\Delta t$ I can switch from number of occurrences to the amount of time in a given measure bin, and in this case the sum of all the bins will be the total amount of observation time, measured in minutes

Comment: Is $\Delta t$ measure dependent?

Comment: $\Delta t$ is chosen to be short enough so that the measurement can be assumed to be constant across the time interval